# When did democracy become popular?

Tags: political-history, democracy

After the Greek and Rome, democracy died out. So when have this system become popular? Which country were the first to adopt it after Rome? And how did it become so widely used?

Comment: I think you should specify more exacly what do you mean by *democracy*...